# JFrame.remove(Component comp) "destroys" my component?

Tags: java, oracle, swing, memory-leaks

I want to know if the usage of JFrame's remove(Component comp) method releases the component from memory and destroys it or is it kept to future use? I'm worried about memory leak and I couldn't find a clue at [oracle's documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#remove%28java.awt.Component%29)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JFrame.remove only removes the component from the JFrame.

Whether the component is removed from memory depends on whether there is any other reference to that object.

If the JFrame was the last thing referencing the component, the component will be removed by Java's garbage collection.

If there is still another active reference elsewhere in your code, you need to remove that reference too, before it will be garbage collected.

(In theory... Java may or may not Garbage Collect your object, as it sees fit. It tends to be more aggressive as you run out of memory though, and can normally be trusted to get on with the job)

Comment: Let me see if I got you; I need to kill my parent JFrame to kill it's panel sons otherwise they will not be collected, is that it?

Comment: No, you just need to remove the panel from the JFrame (ie removing the JFrame's reference to the panel) and remove any OTHER references to that panel. Eg if in your Main() method you did panel2 = new JPane(); and then added panel2 to your JFrame, you may need to also set panel2 = null before the garbage collection picks it up - otherwise it doesn't know whether you ever intend to use panel2 again.

Comment: The above may not be a problem if you did yourFrame.add(new JPanel()) or similar, or if the original reference was within a function which is no longer running etc. It only matters if you still have a reference to the JPanel somewhere in your code

Answer (score 1):

Java has garbage collector that gather unused objects and remove them. You don't need to worry about it unless you call C/C++ methods through JNI. It is possible to have a memory leak if these methods create their own objects but don't delete them.